# Selenium drivers don't remember user authentication

Tags: authentication, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The application I'm testing requires a login with the user's Google account. Every time I log in, it displays/requires that I select the 'Allow Access' button as if it doesn't remember that I have already added it to my list of Authorized Access for my Google account. This doesn't happen when I test manually, only when I'm running Selenium. Has anyone come across an issue like this or know of a solution? Thanks in advance.

```
WebDriver driver = selenium_driver.get(); // using chrome driver 
baseUrl = defaults.getProperty("base_url"); // this is set to my localhost 
helper.ConnectToURL(baseUrl);
```

When this started happening, I had been using Selenium 2.28.0--since then, I've updated to 2.31.0 but it's exhibiting the same behavior.

Comment: Post the Browser launching code which you using.

Comment: As this is being caused due to deletion of cookies, one temporary workaround can be...
use the same browser instance for all the test cases execution. Reuse it for all the next test cases requiring Google account authentication.

Comment: @Manigandan: Sure, just added to the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:**  This is currently not possible according to the ChromeDriver wiki.  It states in the "Known Issues" section "Cannot specify a custom profile". (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

At some point when it is fixed, I would suggest creating or using the default chrome profile that has your authorized access set that your test uses whenever it starts up.

According to the ChromeDriver wiki: "By default, ChromeDriver will create a new temporary profile for each session".

Checkout this post for more in depth information regarding capabilities: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/CapabilitiesAndSwitches

I do my work in .NET and Windows; my set up would look something like this:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default");
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, chromeOptions);
ChromeDriver chromeDriver= new ChromeDriver(this.Environment.ChromeDriverLocation, chromeOptions);
```

If you are not limited to using Chrome for your tests you are able to create and use custom profiles using Firefox.

Comment: Oh, interesting! The thing is this had never happened before--I was able to log in through Selenium without having to grant access each time. Is this a newer issue?

Comment: I cannot say for certain.  I mainly do my testing in Firefox using a custom profile so I don't get security certificate alerts.